# How do I find my Fully Quantified Domain Name on Linux?

Tags: linux, fqdn

My domain name is for example: company1.tk

My Hostname of the server is also: company1.tk

So what would my fully quantified domain name be?

Many Thanks

Comment: It's should be the outputs of `hostname` and `hostname -d` combined, which is returned by `hostname --fqdn`.

Comment: You can also use `dnsdomainname` to return your domain on the command line.  It is provided by the `net-tools` package that is widely available and installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply type:

```
$ hostname
```

which will output like

- rahul-laptop : This will be your computer name.
- nixcraft.in : This will be your DNS domain name.
- rahul-laptop.nixcraft.in : This will be your computer name with Fully Qualified Domain Name.

And if you want can enter:

```
$ hostname -d
```

which will give you the result.

Comment: Thanks, found it now. Cheers!